# REMOTE_ADDR and IPv6 in PHP

Tags: php, apache, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

Is it safe to assume that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` always returns a **IPv4 address**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The REMOTE_ADDR key is set by the web server, not PHP. If the web server listens on v6 and the user connects that way, it'll be a v6 address

Comment: +1, Thanks! I'm gonna try to figure out how I can convert an IPv6 address to a number.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php will convert v4 and v6 "string" addresses to their packed representation.

Comment: @Michael IPv6 has many text representations. Is there a standard representation returned by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: @Pacerier You'll get the normal compacted IPv6 addresses or IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses on a dual-stack system.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a bad IP address reported to php in REMOTE_ADDR from Apache 2.

It was '183.60..244.37'.

So the answer to your question, "Is it safe to assume...", I think is definitely **no**, REMOTE_ADDR can not be trusted.

As far as I know it is reported to PHP from the server, in my case Apache.  Why it was bad I am still trying to figure out.  I do know this.  It came in as part of a batch of attack requests.  Sometimes it was 183.60.244.37 and sometimes it was 183.60..244.37.

See also [this](http://rewindlife.com/2004/04/20/remote_addr-and-remote_host-not-safe-for-use-in-security/).

Comment: Nice to know, probably some Apache bug no?

Comment: A php developer just told me REMOTE_ADDR comes from cgi and so from the server's tcp connection, and not http.  But I'm still working on finding how the server could be reporting this to php, if that is what is happening.